# Why not use a standard hose clamp instead of OEM one-time use clip?

Tags: steering, connector

1995 Integra LS 4 door. Both, Part 11 (Tie-Rod Dust Seals) are to be replaced. Part 7 is the OEM single-use $14 clip:. Two clips are required for the job. I have seen videos with zip ties and wonder if it would be reasonable to use a standard hose clamp?   $30 for two clips seems excessive, however, if there is good reason to use a single-use clip then I'd like to understand the reason to use it over a garden variety hose clamp.

I am particularly interested in the responses from those who have installed these seals / boots: if you have done this please state this in your response and any lessons learned \ details.  Thank you

[Link to enumerated parts list for diagram](http://www.acurapartsnow.com/auto-parts/1995/acura/integra-sedan/ls-trim/5-speed-manual-engine/chassis-cat/p-s-gear-box-scat/?part_number=53434sd9000)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a steering rack boot that you're replacing - it's a pretty simple job (I do them on the family cars).

DON'T buy the single use clip. It's exactly what you don't need, because it requires a special tool to tighten it up. Only about $25 online, but add that to the two clips, and it's getting up in cost for no real reason.

These boots don't rotate. They're simply there to prevent dirt and grime getting onto the rack piston (looks like two, one at each end, but it's really just one long piece sticking out of part #17 in your diagram).

The best (and cheapest) solution is to use long zip ties to hold them in place (long ones, because they are generally a bit thicker as well as longer). Zip on, and cut the excess off.

You can use ordinary hose clamps - just make sure that the bolt are on the clamp doesn't foul anything when you turn the steering fully left or right.

Comment: I suppose it is more a mechanics stack exchange question, but I'm not unwriting it now.. :)

Comment: fine response: is there any advantage using hose clamp over zip-tie?

Comment: I'd say reusability is the only advantage of a hose clamp - you need to cut most zip ties off if you want to redo the tie. However, you're not likely to be redoing this job too often, so I see no benefit to being able to quickly remove the clamp. Black zip ties look neater, as well. It probably comes down to "what do you have in your toolbox at the moment" :)